# jquery slideToggle's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu div to put the menu list inside

```js
// here is the javascript/jquery

$('#menu-tab').click(function(){
    $("#menu").slideToggle("normal");
});
```

```css
/* for the css */

    #menu {
       width: 220px;
       border: 2px solid #004990;
       float: right;
       margin-right: 15px;
       margin-top: -52px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--menu-->
  <a href="#"><div id="menu-tab">Menu</div></a>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

becuase margin-top: -52px;(which I control the menu position in the page), therefore each time when I click the menu tab, the #menu will slide from -52px. how can I let it slide from 0px?

Comment: `<a><div></div></a>`...seriously?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the style before animating it? Set the margin-top to zero right before you do your sliding.

```
$('#menu-tab').click(function(){
    $("#menu").css("margin-top","0px"); //this should set your menudiv to margin-top:0px
    $("#menu").slideToggle("normal");
});
```

Comment: the reson I use margin-top: -52px; is for fixing the position of menu on the page. If I set it back to zero, the position of the menu is also changed.

Comment: well then the menu is in the correct position already? Then why would you want it to slide from margin-top:0px? Perhaps you could post a screenshot or something cause I can't make much sense out of what you're asking now.